# Concrete type in Web API Controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API Controller `FooController` that looks something like

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> messageDictionary;
    private readonly TimeSpan timeout;

    public FooController(IDictionary<string, string> messageDictionary, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        // set fields
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] string message)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
            {
                CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

                // call some api
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // do some other stuff
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                return Ok();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // LogException
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use this controller, I get an error that states there was no default constructor, which is fine, that much is obvious.

I'm reading the values for the `messageDictionary` from the `web.config` file using a custom config section, which looks something like this in by `Global.asax` file

```
private IDictionary<string, string> messageDictionary;
private TimeSpan controllerTimeout;

// ...

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    messageDictionary = BuildMessageDictionaryFromConfig();

    controllerTimeout = GetControllerTimeoutFromConfig();
}
```

My goal is for the controller to not have to worry about reading stuff from the config, or pulling in the `messageDictionary` from `Global`.

I looked into extending `DefaultControllerFactory` in order to build the controller I need there, but the constructor for my new controller factory was never called, despite registering it in `Global#Application_Start` like

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FooControllerFactory());
```

or

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(FooControllerFactory));
```

I considered making a new `IMessageDictionary` interface so that I could use DI (because I have different `IDictionary<string, string>` fields in different controllers that contain different data), but that doesn't solve the problem of the `timeout` parameter in the constructor.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could inject a service interface that does this work for your controller. I'm not sure if this would really improve your design though.

Comment: Inject a `ITimeoutProvider` and create some simple implementation for it and register that with the DI service. IF you are not using DI then consider a framework like AutoFac.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an `IConfigurationManager` that consolidates all configuration related operations in one place and then you can both include the messages and timeout on that manager (and get an instance through DI).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that custom configuration class tend to be overkill for most needs. This is what I do and it works great. First, create an AppSettings class.

```
public interface IAppSettings
{
    string this[string key] { get; }
}

public class AppSettings : IAppSettings
{
    public string this[string key] => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
}
```

Second, register it with your IoC container. Then on your controller you can just depend on `IAppSettings` and get whatever you need.

```
public FooController(IAppSettings appSettings)
{
    var mySetting = appSettings["MySetting"];
}
```

This also makes it super easy to mock config settings within your unit tests.